# Get the field that is going to be edited in kendo beforeedit event

Tags: events, kendo-grid

I have a dependent column that needs to be editable based on value of the first cell. How can do this using the beforeedit event of kendo grid.

I wish to avoid closing the cell in edit event of kendo grid.

Below is a sample
https://dojo.telerik.com/enodEwub

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this when "Inline" edit mode is used you can use the Grid's cancelRow() method.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
   //....
   edit: onEdit
});

function onEdit(e) {
   //your custom logic
   $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").cancelRow();
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Also, cancelRow is supposed to revert all changes made to that row.

Comment: oh! let me check some other solution for you

Comment: Actually closeCell works perfectly in yout casee https://dojo.telerik.com/enodEwub/2 , why you don't want to use that option?

Comment: Yes. Finally ended up in using closeCell() along with grid.table.focus(). I was hoping to get hold of current column inside beforeedit so that the focus is not lost.